# How to use apply_ufunc depending on data dims?

Tags: python, interpolation, python-xarray

I want to interpolate 3D array `air (time, lat, lon)` with one 2D array `newlat (time, lon)` which depends on time and lon.

### For loop method

```
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

air = (
    xr.tutorial.load_dataset("air_temperature")
    .air.sortby("lat")  # np.interp needs coordinate in ascending order
    .isel(time=slice(4), lon=slice(3))
)  # choose a small subset for convenience


newlat = xr.DataArray(np.random.rand(air.sizes['time'], air.sizes['lon'])*75,
                      dims=['time', 'lon'],
                      coords={'time': air.time, 'lon': air.lon}
)


# create empty array to save result
result = np.empty((4, 3))

# loop each dim
for t in range(air.sizes['time']):
    for lon in range(air.sizes['lon']):
        # interpolation relying on time and lon
        f = interp1d(air.lat, air.isel(time=t, lon=lon), kind='linear', fill_value='extrapolate')
        result[t, lon] = f(newlat.isel(time=t, lon=lon))
```

### apply_ufunc method

```
def interp1d_np(data, x, xi):
    f = interp1d(x, data, kind='linear', fill_value='extrapolate')
    return f(xi)

t_index = 0
lon_index = 0

xr.apply_ufunc(
    interp1d_np,
    air.isel(time=t_index, lon=lon_index),
    air.lat,
    newlat.isel(time=t_index, lon=lon_index),
    input_core_dims=[["lat"], ["lat"], []],
    exclude_dims=set(("lat",)),
    vectorize=True,
)
```

Note that t_idnex and lon_index are the same for input `air` and `newlat`.
The code above only works for one specific part of `air`. How to apply it to the whole `air` DataArray?

### Temperary Solution

We can just use the embedded function like this:

```
air.interp(lat=newlat, kwargs={"fill_value": None})
```

But, I'm still curious of how to use `apply_ufunc` in this situation, because users may have their own functions instead of the simple interpolation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're basically there. Delete the `.isel` calls and it will work! `vectorize=True` will automatically loop over the "non core dimensions" i.e. `time` and `lon` in this case.

```py
xr.apply_ufunc(
    interp1d_np,
    air,
    air.lat,
    newlat,
    input_core_dims=[["lat"], ["lat"], []],
    exclude_dims=set(("lat",)),
    vectorize=True,
)
```